# Django 1.5.4 auth - error while syncdb or createsuperuser

Tags: django, django-authentication

I dont know what happened, but suddenly syncdb stopped working.

When i call "**python manage.py syncdb**", im getting such messages:

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
... (my apps)

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username: m
Email address: m@m.com
First name: m
Last name: m
Password: 
Password (again): 
DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
```

Same when i call "**python manage.py createsuperuser**".

User is created, i can login, but has no any rights. I cant also browse admin page (displays login window). What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you using the built-in auth User or have you customized the User via `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: Can you include your User model in the question please.

Comment: Heh, you felt good ;) I didnt know that another dev included there (in user model) post save function that adds user to a group, which of course does not exist while syncing db (thats error). Thanks you, problem solved :)